# Why power is proportional to resistance in $I^2R$ and inversely proportional in $V^2/R$?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

In one relation electrical power is directly proportional to resistance while in other it is inversely promotional.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296236/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361617/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, the power in an electrical element is given by

$$P=IV$$

where $V$ is the voltage applied on the element and $I$ is the current that flows through it. It just happened that a resistor $R$ also satisfies Ohm's law $V=IR$, such that the power dissipated in it can be written also as

$$P=I^{2}R=\frac{V^2}{R}$$

The key point is that $I$ and $V$ are related, and cannot be stated independently in the case of resistors.